# How to read all folder names from particular folder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read all folders from particular folder using JavaScript on local-host. So how to read folders from particular folder.

Comment: We can't access os files using client side javascript as it only works for browser but for ie you can do it by using Active-x object.

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.